# Assiging 3 triggers to sensitivity list

Tags: verilog, hdl

I am trying to implement a guessing game on the ALTERA DE2 board using verilog HDL. Player1 chooses a number from 0 to 7 and Player2 guesses the number and vice versa till one reaches score3.
But it seems like the submit button and count button don't work at the same time. If I comment out one of submit or count the other one works just fine. The full code is provided below.

```
module test2 (
   input [2:0] answer_pin,
   input count,
   input submit,
   input reset,
   output reg [6:0] phase,
   output reg [6:0] answer,
   output reg [6:0] red_state,
   output reg [6:0] red_score,
   output reg [6:0] blue_state,
   output reg [6:0] blue_score

);
   wire trig = (count & submit);
   reg [2:0] count_value;
   reg [1:0] phase_value;
   reg red_state_value;
   reg [1:0] red_score_value;
   reg blue_state_value;
   reg [1:0] blue_score_value;

   always @(negedge reset or negedge trig)
   begin

      if (~reset) begin
         phase_value <= 2'b01;
         blue_state_value <= 1'b0;
         blue_score_value <= 2'b00;
         red_state_value <= 1'b1;
         red_score_value <= 2'b00;
         count_value <= 3'b000;
      end


else if(~submit) begin
    if(phase_value == 2'b01) begin 
    phase_value <= 2'b10;
    end
    else if(phase_value == 2'b00) begin
    phase_value <= 2'b00;
    end
    else begin
        if(red_state_value == 2'b01) begin
            if(answer_pin == count_value) begin
                if(blue_score_value == 2'b10) begin
                    blue_score_value <= blue_score_value + 1'b1;
                    phase_value <= 2'b00;
                end
                else begin
                    red_state_value <= 1'b0;
                    blue_state_value <= 1'b1;
                    blue_score_value <= blue_score_value + 1'b1;
                    count_value <= 3'b000;
                    phase_value <= 2'b01;
                end
            end
            else begin
                if(red_score_value == 2'b10) begin
                    red_score_value <= red_score_value + 1'b1;
                    phase_value <= 2'b00;
                end
                else begin
                    red_state_value <= 1'b0;
                    blue_state_value <= 1'b1;
                    red_score_value <= red_score_value + 1'b1;
                    count_value <= 3'b000;
                    phase_value <= 2'b01;
                end
            end
        else begin
            if(answer_pin == count_value) begin
                if(red_score_value == 2'b10) begin
                red_score_value <= red_score_value + 1'b1;
                phase_value <= 2'b00;
                end
                else begin
                        red_state_value <= 1'b1;
                        blue_state_value <= 1'b0;
                        blue_score_value <= blue_score_value + 1'b1;
                        count_value <= 3'b000;
                        phase_value <= 2'b01;
                end
            end
            else begin
                if(blue_score_value == 2'b10) begin
                    blue_score_value <= blue_score_value + 1'b1;
                    phase_value <= 2'b00;
                end
                else begin
                    red_state_value <= 1'b1;
                    blue_state_value <= 1'b0;
                    blue_score_value <= blue_score_value + 1'b1;
                    count_value <= 3'b000;
                    phase_value <= 2'b01;
                end
            end
        end
    end
end



   else begin
      if (phase_value!=2'b00) begin
         if (phase_value == 2'b01) begin
               if (count_value == 3'b111) begin
                  if(red_state_value == 1'b1) begin
                     if(blue_score_value == 2'b10) begin
                        blue_score_value <= blue_score_value + 1'b1;
                        phase_value <= 2'b00;
                     end
                     else begin 
                        blue_state_value <= 1'b1;
                        red_state_value <= 1'b0; 
                        blue_score_value <= blue_score_value + 1'b1;
                        count_value <= 3'b000;
                     end
                  end
                  else begin
                     if(red_score_value == 2'b10) begin
                        red_score_value <= red_score_value + 1'b1;
                        phase_value <= 2'b00;
                     end
                     else begin
                        red_state_value <= 1'b1;
                        blue_state_value <= 1'b0;
                        red_score_value <= red_score_value + 1'b1;
                        count_value <= 3'b000;
                     end
                  end
               end

            else 
               count_value <= count_value + 1'b1;
            end


      end
   end

   end

   always @(*) 
   begin
   case(answer_pin)
   3'b000: answer=7'b1000000;
   3'b001: answer=7'b1111001;
   3'b010: answer=7'b0100100;
   3'b011: answer=7'b0110000;  
   3'b100: answer=7'b0011001;
   3'b101: answer=7'b0010010;
   3'b110: answer=7'b0000010;
   3'b111: answer=7'b1011000;
   default: answer=7'b1000000;
   endcase

   case(red_state_value)
   1'b1: red_state = 7'b0111111;
   1'b0: red_state = 7'b1111111;
   default: red_state=7'b0111111;
   endcase

   case(blue_state_value)
   1'b1: blue_state = 7'b0111111;
   1'b0: blue_state = 7'b1111111;
   default: blue_state = 7'b1111111;
   endcase

   case(red_score_value)
   2'b00: red_score = 7'b1000000;
   2'b01: red_score = 7'b1111001;
   2'b10: red_score = 7'b0100100;
   2'b11: red_score = 7'b0110000;
   default: red_score= 7'b1000000;
   endcase

   case(blue_score_value)
   2'b00: blue_score = 7'b1000000;
   2'b01: blue_score = 7'b1111001;
   2'b10: blue_score = 7'b0100100;
   2'b11: blue_score = 7'b0110000;
   default: blue_score= 7'b1000000;
   endcase

   case(phase_value)
   2'b00: phase = 7'b1000000;
   2'b01: phase = 7'b1111001;
   2'b10: phase = 7'b0100100;
   default: phase= 7'b1111001;
   endcase

   end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

At first sight it looks like you forgot an end. I used my preferred indentation and found you forgot an `end`. Try to be consistent in your indentation.

Didn't look at the code itself so it might still not work as expected.

```
module test2 (
    input [2:0] answer_pin,
    input count,
    input submit,
    input reset,
    output reg [6:0] phase,
    output reg [6:0] answer,
    output reg [6:0] red_state,
    output reg [6:0] red_score,
    output reg [6:0] blue_state,
    output reg [6:0] blue_score
);
    wire trig = (count & submit);
    reg [2:0] count_value;
    reg [1:0] phase_value;
    reg red_state_value;
    reg [1:0] red_score_value;
    reg blue_state_value;
    reg [1:0] blue_score_value;

    always @(negedge reset or negedge trig) begin

        if (~reset) begin
            phase_value <= 2'b01;
            blue_state_value <= 1'b0;
            blue_score_value <= 2'b00;
            red_state_value <= 1'b1;
            red_score_value <= 2'b00;
            count_value <= 3'b000;
        end else if(~submit) begin
            if(phase_value == 2'b01) begin 
                phase_value <= 2'b10;
            end else if(phase_value == 2'b00) begin
                phase_value <= 2'b00;
            end else begin
                if(red_state_value == 2'b01) begin
                    if(answer_pin == count_value) begin
                        if(blue_score_value == 2'b10) begin
                            blue_score_value <= blue_score_value + 1'b1;
                            phase_value <= 2'b00;
                        end else begin
                            red_state_value <= 1'b0;
                            blue_state_value <= 1'b1;
                            blue_score_value <= blue_score_value + 1'b1;
                            count_value <= 3'b000;
                            phase_value <= 2'b01;
                        end
                    end else begin
                        if(red_score_value == 2'b10) begin
                            red_score_value <= red_score_value + 1'b1;
                            phase_value <= 2'b00;
                        end else begin
                            red_state_value <= 1'b0;
                            blue_state_value <= 1'b1;
                            red_score_value <= red_score_value + 1'b1;
                            count_value <= 3'b000;
                            phase_value <= 2'b01;
                        end
                    end 
                end else begin //added an end here
                        if(answer_pin == count_value) begin 
                            if(red_score_value == 2'b10) begin
                                red_score_value <= red_score_value + 1'b1;
                                phase_value <= 2'b00;
                            end else begin
                                red_state_value <= 1'b1;
                                blue_state_value <= 1'b0;
                                blue_score_value <= blue_score_value + 1'b1;
                                count_value <= 3'b000;
                                phase_value <= 2'b01;
                            end
                        end else begin
                            if(blue_score_value == 2'b10) begin
                                blue_score_value <= blue_score_value + 1'b1;
                                phase_value <= 2'b00;
                            end else begin
                                red_state_value <= 1'b1;
                                blue_state_value <= 1'b0;
                                blue_score_value <= blue_score_value + 1'b1;
                                count_value <= 3'b000;
                                phase_value <= 2'b01;
                            end
                        end
                    end
                end
            end else begin
                if (phase_value!=2'b00) begin
                    if (phase_value == 2'b01) begin
                        if (count_value == 3'b111) begin
                            if(red_state_value == 1'b1) begin
                                if(blue_score_value == 2'b10) begin
                                    blue_score_value <= blue_score_value + 1'b1;
                                    phase_value <= 2'b00;
                                end else begin 
                                    blue_state_value <= 1'b1;
                                    red_state_value <= 1'b0; 
                                    blue_score_value <= blue_score_value + 1'b1;
                                    count_value <= 3'b000;
                                end
                            end else begin
                                if(red_score_value == 2'b10) begin
                                    red_score_value <= red_score_value + 1'b1;
                                    phase_value <= 2'b00;
                                end else begin
                                    red_state_value <= 1'b1;
                                    blue_state_value <= 1'b0;
                                    red_score_value <= red_score_value + 1'b1;
                                    count_value <= 3'b000;
                                end
                            end
                        end else begin
                            count_value <= count_value + 1'b1;
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end

    always @(*) begin
        case(answer_pin)
            3'b000: answer=7'b1000000;
            3'b001: answer=7'b1111001;
            3'b010: answer=7'b0100100;
            3'b011: answer=7'b0110000;  
            3'b100: answer=7'b0011001;
            3'b101: answer=7'b0010010;
            3'b110: answer=7'b0000010;
            3'b111: answer=7'b1011000;
            default: answer=7'b1000000;
        endcase

        case(red_state_value)
           1'b1: red_state = 7'b0111111;
           1'b0: red_state = 7'b1111111;
           default: red_state=7'b0111111;
        endcase

        case(blue_state_value)
            1'b1: blue_state = 7'b0111111;
            1'b0: blue_state = 7'b1111111;
            default: blue_state = 7'b1111111;
        endcase

        case(red_score_value)
            2'b00: red_score = 7'b1000000;
            2'b01: red_score = 7'b1111001;
            2'b10: red_score = 7'b0100100;
            2'b11: red_score = 7'b0110000;
            default: red_score= 7'b1000000;
        endcase

        case(blue_score_value)
            2'b00: blue_score = 7'b1000000;
            2'b01: blue_score = 7'b1111001;
            2'b10: blue_score = 7'b0100100;
            2'b11: blue_score = 7'b0110000;
            default: blue_score= 7'b1000000;
        endcase

        case(phase_value)
            2'b00: phase = 7'b1000000;
            2'b01: phase = 7'b1111001;
            2'b10: phase = 7'b0100100;
            default: phase= 7'b1111001;
        endcase
    end

endmodule
```